# Unable to load Android Support Libraries in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android Studio. I am building project using Cordova. As soon as I add camera plugin, and when I build project I get the error

```
Error:(25, 42) java: package android.support.support.v4.content does not exist.
```

I checked all the support libraries and they are installed in my sdk manager but as aar. There is not JAR file. My project is also not on Gradle. Can you please help me in this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfrhi.png)

here is the window path of my support library.

Here is my Gradle file :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3v59.png)

Comment: How did you configure the support lib into your project? Did you?
Please share your code

Comment: I did not, I just installed it from SDK manager.

Comment: Can you please help me out like I don't know how to configure support lib in my android cordova project?

Comment: post code bulild.gredle of your app and project

Comment: This is my gradle file :

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        compile "com.android.support:support.v4."
    }

Comment: I am not making project using gradle

Comment: Post your build.gradle file pls

Comment: Gradle screenshot added

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the support-v4 dependency **in the wrong block** inside the `build.gradle` file.

Remove it from the `buildscript` block and add in the `dependencies` block.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
  }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1"
}
```

Comment: No still same error. My project is not on Gradle, does it effect?